# jquery adds a class to an image. Doesn't work in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

http://steph.net23.net/work.php here is my test link. This page has a jquery script in it that adds a class to the first image. This works in all browsers except Chrome. It's like it adds it and then the image disappears. Anybody know why?

Comment: Your host apparently thinks you're up to something: "You see this page, because the system administrator of 000webhost.com is currently checking this website for malicious content."

Comment: Oh god it didn't have that when i looked at it last. They do that every once in a while when you start a new site. Try again in 24 hours. They'll be done by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/galleria/issues/detail?id=41#c6). It was hard to find resources b/c when you google the galleria plugin the url is broken for the galleria home.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the Galleria script you are using. It uses browser detection that specifies Safari (jQuery.browser.safari) when it should be jQuery.browser.webkit (which both Safari and Chrome use). What's more Firebug gives the following message:

> The jQuery team recommends against
>   using jQuery.browser, please try to
>   use feature detection instead (see
>   jQuery.support).

That script looks to predate Chrome so it probably isn't properly handling it in a number of ways. Unless you know how to fix it I'd recommend looking elsewhere for a more up to date plugin.